# Chmod directory from other module by puppet

Tags: puppet, chmod

I'm using a 3rd part puppet module which I wish not to change (Tomcat). It creates a directory with mode=644, which I wish to change to 664 (recursively).

When I'm trying this, puppet is unhappy since this resource is already defined in the other module.

```
file { '/var/lib/tomcat' :
    ensure    => directory,
    mode => 0664,
    recurse    => true,
}
```

Any ideas how can I go around this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *collector* syntax to override some attributes for a resource that has already been declared.

```
File<| title == '/var/lib/tomcat' |> {
  mode => '0664'
}
```

Use this sparingly. Incompatible overrides will still clash, and your manifests become difficult to debug.

The safest approach is to make the attribute a module parameter (by sending an appropriate patch upstream).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the 'exec' resource type.

```
exec {"chmod -R  664 /var/lib/tomcat":
    path => "/bin",
    command => "chmod -R 664 .",
    cwd => "/var/lib/tomcat"
}
```

It's the only workaround i found to avoid duplicate resource name

Comment: This is problematic because two distinct resources manage the same entity. Every agent transaction will perform a flip-flop between the conflicting states, cluttering your reports.

Comment: You are right, but i don't know any other ways...
The better should of course be to override of the tomcat module, but he doesn't want to ;)

Answer (score 0):

in bash you can use

`cd /var/lib
chmod -R 664 Tomcat`